# How I can solve the problem ?Traceback: File "C:/Users/rawaa/PycharmProjects/huffman/deempade.py", line 56, seed= pickle.load(fp) EOFError

Tags: python, pickle

when I run the code I get the following error .please help me to solve the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rawaa/PycharmProjects/huffman/deempade.py", line 56, in <module>
    seed= pickle.load(fp)
EOFError
```

The code is

```
with open('pickled/keys', 'rb') as fp:
     d_codewords = pickle.load(fp)
     message_length = pickle.load(fp)
     seed= pickle.load(fp)
     null_chars = pickle.load(fp)
filename = raw_input("Enter the stego file name\n")
bin_message = de_embed(filename, seed, message_length, null_chars)
print "The retrieved binary message from file is : {}".format(bin_message)
decoded = decode(bin_message, d_codewords)
print "The message after Huffman Decoding is : {}".format(decoded)
with open('pickled/RSA_Keys', 'rb') as fp:
    key = pickle.load(fp)
print 'The RSA decrypted message is : ' + ''.join(map(chr, RSA.decrypt(key[1], decoded)))
```

Comment: The `pickle` file format ends with a special marker and it looks like the file being loaded doesn't have one. The last byte of all pickle files should be the `pickle.STOP` opcode.

Comment: Why are you performing the exact same operation, `pickle.load(fp)`, four times? Am I missing something? Why are you using Python 2? Where is the [mcve]?